# How to remove the whitespace after and before the navbar? Using tailwindcss

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I'm trying to remove the whitespace before and after this page. I've already tried all the solution I found here of changing the margin to 0, but the problem still shows up.

[image: Image of the page]

My html is like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Names Generator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/Images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/Images/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/Images/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/Images/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Images/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/browserconfig.xml">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body class="tw-m-0 tw-bg-cyan-600">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary tw-m-0">
        <div class="container-fluid tw-bg-cyan-600">
            <a class="navbar-brand tw-text-white" href="#">Home</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler tw-text-white" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon tw-fill-white"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse tablet:tw-flex tablet:tw-justify-end" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link tw-text-white" href="#">Post 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a class="nav-link tw-text-white" href="#">Post 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container tw-m-0">
        <h1 class="h1 text-center tw-m-0">Generator</h1>
        <img src="/Images/android-chrome-192x192.png" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="Name Generator Logo"
            width="40" height="40" href="#" />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white gaps are from the vertical `padding` from Bootstrap's `.navbar` rule:

```css
.navbar {
  /* … */
  padding: var(--bs-navbar-padding-y) var(--bs-navbar-padding-x);
}
```

You can remove the vertical padding in several ways. For example, by overriding the padding with `!tw-py-0`:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Names Generator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/Images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/Images/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/Images/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/Images/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Images/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/browserconfig.xml">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>
</head>

<body class="tw-m-0 tw-bg-cyan-600">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary tw-m-0 !tw-py-0">
        <div class="container-fluid tw-bg-cyan-600">
            <a class="navbar-brand tw-text-white" href="#">Home</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler tw-text-white" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon tw-fill-white"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse tablet:tw-flex tablet:tw-justify-end" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link tw-text-white" href="#">Post 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a class="nav-link tw-text-white" href="#">Post 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container tw-m-0">
        <h1 class="h1 text-center tw-m-0">Generator</h1>
        <img src="/Images/android-chrome-192x192.png" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="Name Generator Logo"
            width="40" height="40" href="#" />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You could also set `--bs-navbar-padding-y` to `0%`:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Names Generator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/Images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/Images/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/Images/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/Images/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Images/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/browserconfig.xml">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>
</head>

<body class="tw-m-0 tw-bg-cyan-600">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary tw-m-0 ![--bs-navbar-padding-y:0%]">
        <div class="container-fluid tw-bg-cyan-600">
            <a class="navbar-brand tw-text-white" href="#">Home</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler tw-text-white" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon tw-fill-white"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse tablet:tw-flex tablet:tw-justify-end" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link tw-text-white" href="#">Post 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a class="nav-link tw-text-white" href="#">Post 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container tw-m-0">
        <h1 class="h1 text-center tw-m-0">Generator</h1>
        <img src="/Images/android-chrome-192x192.png" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="Name Generator Logo"
            width="40" height="40" href="#" />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! This solves it! New to webdev just trying stuff out. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Code example don't reproduce the image related problem.

It looks like you defined the background-color of the child div of the `navbar`, and this class has a padding.
Remove the padding from the `navbar` class.